# Chart with time measurement in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, charts, data-analysis, measurement

I want to do a chart that shows the execution time of a specific method which is executed several times and in which the amount of executions is random, which means that the time won't always be the same. My problem is how to integrate the data from my array "sample" into the chart, so that the data is displayed correctly. Right now it's not showing anything in the graph and I can only see the grid without any content. What did I wrong that it doesn't work? Here's my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1000, 600);
        Button start = new Button();
        int n = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        start.setText("Start");
        start.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 30;");
        start.setOnAction(e->{
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            long[] sample = run(n);
            start.setVisible(false);
            analyse(sample, pane);
        });
        pane.getChildren().add(start);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Time statistics");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void analyse(long[] sample, StackPane pane) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long max = sample[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < sample.length; ++i) {
            if (sample[i] > max) {
                max = sample[i];
            }
        }

        //Create Chart
        //Create the X-Axis
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Run number");
        xAxis.setLowerBound(0);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(100);
        xAxis.setTickUnit(1);

        //Create the Y-Axis
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setLabel("Time");

        //Create Line Chart
        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.setTitle("Time measurement");

        //Set the data for the chart
        ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Number,Number>> chartData = FXCollections.<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>>observableArrayList();
        chart.setData(chartData);

        //Set properties of the StackPane
        pane.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-color: blue;");

        pane.getChildren().add(chart);
    }

    private long[] run(int n) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long[] delta = new long[n];
        while (n > 0) {
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            execute();
            delta[delta.length - n] = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            --n;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    /**
     * Output of a random number between 0 and 100
     */
    private void execute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int n = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        int count = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            ++count;
            --n;
        }
        System.out.println("Random number:");
        System.out.println(count);
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't put any data in the chart. You need to create a `Series`, populate it with `XYChart.Data` objects, and add the series to `chartData`.

Comment: whatever the problem: you __must not__ sleep the fx thread

Comment: I sleep the thread, so that after clicking the start button, it waits a second before starting.

Comment: @JoAn Why would you want to do that? Even if you have good reason to do so, use a `PauseTransition` or similar, so you don't block the FX Application, which, as stated, you must not do.